# .NET equivalent to Delphi's "DebugHook" variable to test for presence of debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, oxygene

When a program is running under the control of the debugger in the Delphi IDE, it is possible to detect this because the variable "DebugHook" is set to a value <> 0.

Is there an equally easy way to check for the debugger when debugging a .NET program in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same in .NET reference "System.Diagnostics" and add this code

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) then
   // Program is running under the control of the debugger
```

Comment: Which .net language is this? Are you sure we need yet another dupe?

Comment: I needed this for a program written in RemObjects Oxygene. I think the question is justified as neither Delphi nor "DebugHook" are mentioned in the other questions / answers.

Comment: The language in this answer is the language asked for in the question (tags):  **Oxygene**.  The question you previously marked as a duplicate is phrased in terms of reference to a *specific other language* and is tagged with that language ("C#") and "WinForms" neither of which are relevant to the question or the answer which is more generally applicable to .net.  With such a **key** difference the questions may well be similar but they are not duplicates.